# “Event log is full” during repair of Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

Problem starts with random Visual Studio 2012 crashes. It crashes after a few minutes of navigation through the code. I've disabled all the extensions, but it didn't help. I made an attempt to repair VS 2012 via "Add remove programs", but got the message: "The event log file is full". See the attached picture:

[image]

I've rechecked the log size at Computer Management panel. Log files were about 30 Mb. It looks fine.

Does anyone met such a problem? and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the event logs?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, it didn't help